# Cumulative totals field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
Key       TypeSeq   Type    Duration
-------------------------------------
29671461    10      1001       4
29671461    20      1002       2
29671461    30      1003       0
29671461    40      1004       0
29671461    70      1007     261
29671463    10      1001       3
29671463    20      1002       5
29671463    30      1003       7
29671463    40      1004       8
29671463    70      1007     261
```

I have found this but I am trying to group by ID rather that sum by it

```
select t1.id, t1.SomeNumt, SUM(t2.SomeNumt) as sum
from @t t1
inner join @t t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.SomeNumt
order by t1.id
```

I need a 5th column that does a cumulative total by key column

Comment: Your columns in your query are totally unrelated to your sample data.

Comment: That’s not my query it was a cumulative total sql I found that didn’t quite fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum()` as a window function. If an `order by` is used together with that, you get a cumulative sum:

```
select "Key", TypeSeq, type, duration, 
       sum(duration) over (partition by "Key" order by TypeSeq) as sum
from the_table
order by "Key", TypeSeq;
```